# Spring Security returns 403 Forbidden exception even when i throw custom exception with response code 400 from unsecured route

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have ignored route throwing a runtime exception but spring security converts it into 403 forbidden exception. I just want it to show my exception with msg in response body as it was showing before adding spring security.

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String[] IGNORE_ROUTES = new String[] { "/api/users/register", "/api/users/login" };

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(IGNORE_ROUTES);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors()
        .and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(IGNORE_ROUTES).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().exceptionHandling()
        .and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    }

}
```

UserController.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public User loginUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.login(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public User registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        throw new RuntimeException("My Message");
    }

}
```

(showing exception as it is supposed to)
console output on sending request:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: My Message
    at com.nagarro.expiry.management.controller.UserController.registerUser(UserController.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:204) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

(Doesn't Match With Exception throw instead its 403 forbidden)
Postman Response:
[PostMan Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfNFi.png)

Comment: Shouldn't you add a filter to have the register endpoint as open for all?

Comment: In configure(WebSecurity web) method i added login & register paths to ignore routes which makes it open for all

Comment: @GirishArora Show your request headers. Did you send `Origin` header?